# checkbox checked test with submit button

Tags: jquery, html, forms, checkbox

I've searched previous threads but non helped me with this.
I know HTML5 has an option to add a "required" attr to checkboxes, which would avoid all of this, but my teacher wants us to do it anyway...

So I have a checkbox and a submit button. I want the form to submit ONLY if the checkbox is checked.

Here are my codes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check" id="test" value="unchecked" onchange="checked()" />some text here<br />
            <input type="submit" onclick="check()"/>
```

and the JS:

```
    function checked() { //This function changes the value of the checkbox for the next function.
if ($("#test").val() == "unchecked") {
    $("#test").val("checked")
}
else {
    $("#test").val("unchecked")
}
};

function check() { //This function tests if the "contact us" form should be sent.
if ($("#test").val() == "checked") {
    $("#test").submit()
}
else {
    alert("please agree to terms blah blah blah")
}
};
```

I used F12 to check the DOM of the page, and there seems to be a problem in the first function (the value of the checkbox doesn't change...)

Also I'm not sure I'm using the .submit() correctly. Will it submit to the original address I gave for the form?

Comment: To check if checkbox is checked use `$("#test").is(":checked")` or `$("#test").prop("checked")`

Comment: `$('form').on('submit', function() { return $("#test").is(":checked"); });`

Comment: What is the $('form')? Where am I supposed to put this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<label for="test"><input type="checkbox" name="check" id="test" value="unchecked" />some text here</label><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

and js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').on('submit', check);
});

function check() {
    return $('#test').is(':checked');
}
```

Comment: Well I don't know how, but after everything, I simply deleted the button, added a new one, followed these instructions and it suddenly worked...
That was very strange indeed.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Remove the onclick inline code, replace with event bindings (better practice)
(2) Trap the submit event on the form (using form's ID attr)

```
$('#myFormID').submit(function(e){
    if ( !$('#test').is(':checked') ) return false;
    alert('Form has submitted'); //REMOVE - ONLY FOR EXAMPLE
    e.preventDefault(); //REMOVE - ONLY FOR EXAMPLE
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c1a5pnp8/)

---

Here is full code for the page:

```
<!DocType HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#myFormID').submit(function(e){
                if ( !$('#test').is(':checked') ) return false;
                alert('Form has submitted'); //REMOVE - ONLY FOR EXAMPLE
                e.preventDefault(); //REMOVE - ONLY FOR EXAMPLE
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form id="myFormID">
            <input type="checkbox" name="check" id="test" value="unchecked" />some text here<br />
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is event binding?

Comment: @NimrodYanai It's when you add an event listener to an element. In the above example: `$('#myFormID').submit()` binds a listener for the `submit` event to the element with ID `myFormID`.  Thus, when that event  (`submit`) fires on that element (`#myFormID`), the above code executes.

Comment: Thanx, but that doesn't solve my problem. The code just doesn't seem to recognize the checkbox AT ALL! It won't add, remove or toggle a class, it won't change it's value, nothing. 
F12 gives me a an unclear message about booleans, even after I changed the code (I figured maybe I'll identify classes instead of value).

Comment: Have you included the jQuery library in the `<head>` tags of your page? `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I have. I'm using a tamplet for all my html pages which automatically includes it, my js.js and CSS files.
This is the code I have so far:
'code'    function checked() {
        if ($("#test").hasClass("unchecked")) {
            $("#test").removeClass("unchecked")
        }
        else {
            $("#test").addClass("unchecked")
        }
    };

    function check() {
        if ($("#test").hasClass("unchecked")) {
            alert('some text')
        }
        else {
            $("#contact").submit()
            alert('other text')
        }
    };'code'

Comment: @NimrodYanai Also, did you wrap your script in a `$(function(){ //all code here });` -- aka document.ready -- wrapper? [See this link](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/#launching-code-on-document-ready)

Comment: I did, yes. Except for one function which is out of it because for some reason it doesn't work in side, but it's on another page and has nothing to do with these functions.

Comment: Have you tried removing the inline function calls `<input onclick=callthis() />` and switching to event bindings, as suggested in my answer?  Also, just get your code to do one basic test: `alert("Hello");` after clicking the submit button.

Comment: @NimrodYanai See my revised answer with full HTML code

Comment: I tried swiching to bindings, but it didn't work. There is something fundementally wrong with the basic checkbox, it just doesn't recognize it for some reason...

Comment: Before I do that, I must fix the problem with the checkbox, because right now the form doesn't read it at all!
I've submitted the form for testing, and the textbox doesn't appear in the return form AT ALL. It has a name, it has a value, I've deleted all js codes relating to it, and it still doesn't submit at all.
This is driving me crazy!

Comment: There are two things going on here and to solve them both you should divide and conquer. First, solve the jQuery problem of whether the checkbox is identified as checked on form submit -- use the exact code at top of my answer. Note that the `e.preventDefault()` stops the form from submitting -- that is for testing. *(You must also have an `e` between the function params, as in my code above: `function(e){ //etc }` )*

Comment: THEN verify the fields are being read on form submit.  The `<form>` tag is critical: `<form action="where.php" method="how">`  The `action` attrib specifies the PHP file to receive the form data. The `method` attrib is either `get` or `post`. I always use `post`. This is important, because in the receiving PHP file, you retrieve the form data via the corresponding command: `method="post"` must use `$cb = $_POST['check'];` whereas get would use `$_GET['check']`

Comment: Watch videos 69, 70 and 71 from here: https://www.thenewboston.com/videos.php?cat=11